# ASP.NET MVC 3: Append to sections

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to append to a section. Here is my structure:

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@RenderSection("Css", false)
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/scripts/head.load.min.js")"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg_g">
    @RenderBody()
    <script type="text/javascript">
        @RenderSection("Javascript", false)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Logon.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DMZ.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Logon";
}

@section Javascript += {
    // JAVASCRIPT CODE;
}

<div>
    Stuff
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Register", "Account"); }
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Register2", "Account"); }
</div>
```

Register.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@section Javascript += {
    // More javascript code
}

<div>
    Register stuff
</div>
```

Register2.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@section Javascript += {
    // Even More javascript code
}

<div>
    Register stuff part 2
</div>
```

Hopefully that explains what I'm really trying to do. I would also like to do the same thing with my css section. It would be even better if I could also get it to render the Javascript like this:

```
head.js(
    "@Url.Content("~/Content/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")",
    "@Url.Content("~/Content/scripts/jquery.tools.min.js")",
    "@Url.Content("~/Content/lib/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js")",
// Loop through all javascript files included from the sub views and add them just like above
function () {
    loginTabs.init();
    // Loop through all javascript functions that have been added to the InitFunctions section?
}
)
```

Maybe sections aren't the correct solution to this problem, but I know that there has to be a way to accomplish something like this. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a late entry - but hopefully still useful to someone out there:

I don't know if there is a native method to achieve it but i have been using this for some time now and it's really helpful:

```
public static IHtmlString Resource( this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper, Func<object, HelperResult> Template, string Type )
{
    if( HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Type] != null ) ( (List<Func<object, HelperResult>>)HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Type] ).Add( Template );
    else HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Type] = new List<Func<object, HelperResult>> { Template };

    return new HtmlString( String.Empty );
}

public static IHtmlString RenderResources( this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper, string Type )
{
    if( HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Type] == null ) return new HtmlString( String.Empty );

    var Resources = (List<Func<object, HelperResult>>)HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Type];

    foreach( var Resource in Resources.Where( Resource => Resource != null ) )
    {
        HtmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write( Resource( null ) );
    }

    return new HtmlString( String.Empty );
}
```

The usage is:

```
//This is how you save it
@Html.Resource(@<style>.test{color: #4e4e4e}</style>, "css")

//This is how you read it
@Html.RenderResources("css")
```